# Android View transition like in Amazon App

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, animation

So I am new to Android development and I want to do a animation of a view like [how Amazon does it here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/k7HShTUPvBASliC92). I am referring to sliding the view like this.

Now my question would specifically address the type of the View used in this. Because it doesn't look like its simple XML but somehow I don't think that its a fragment because you need to instantiate fragment in fragment container of sort, and this would be hell to implement.

Is there a way you can extend a view class, define a layout it should return like we have in Activity onCreate and provide functionality (this would be a similar approach like in iOS I guess)? Or how would you do it?

Everything else I understand, the edge swipe to create it and so on...

Comment: That looks like it could be a `ViewPager` or `RecyclerView` with `SnapHelper` or a Fragment. You can just inflate a ViewPager / RecyclerView inside a fragment and load that fragment in a frame layout. And then you can transition the FrameLayout into view when a button is clicked. Seems pretty simple to implement

Comment: Dont mind me for asking but why would you want to transition FrameLayout into view? So you can do translation of it in its Parent View Group?

Comment: You can't really transition a fragment, only views. So it's either the FrameLayout containing the fragment so the whole view moves into the viewport. Or if you are not using a fragment, you can move the parent view of all the views into the screen. Once you are done with the views inside the fragment, the transition is not a big deal. Only like 5 lines.